# I want to remove the ```\u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot;``` from a String

Tags: flutter

While working in flutter I receives this string `"Say \u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot; to Non recording Calls (Observations and Guidelines for Order Placement)(Proficie(Beginer)"`. So from this string I want to remove `\u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot;` this code then I want it like `"Say to Non recording Calls (Observations and Guidelines for Order Placement)(Proficie(Beginer)"`. Anybody have any suggestion.

Comment: `"Say \u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot; to Non recording Calls (Observations and Guidelines for Order Placement)(Proficie(Beginer)".split("\u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot;").join()` Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "Say \u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot; to Non recording Calls (Observations and Guidelines for Order Placement)(Proficie(Beginer)";

print(str.replaceAll("\u0026amp;quot;No\u0026amp;quot;", ""));
```

> The Output :

Say  to Non recording Calls (Observations and Guidelines for Order Placement)(Proficie(Beginer)

Comment: If the answer is useful to u kindly upvote my answer